# CSS for ID not affecting img tag

Tags: html, css, special-characters, image

I came across this issue last night where my CSS would not affect the img tag for the following HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div id="grid"><img src='test.jpg' /></div>
</div>
```

The CSS was as follows:

```
#grid img { position:relative; top:75px; border:5px solid white; }
```

Everything should have been working fine, but when I viewed source on the uploaded CSS document, I found out a special character was being entered at the end of the previous line:

```
#grid p { float:right; font-size:34px; }â€‹
#grid img { position:relative; top:75px; border:5px solid white; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlighting the area and clicking backspace in my IDE fixed the issue. Was about to post question on here, so I thought I'd add the knowledge to save someone else the trouble.